# When can I approximate the convolution integral of two functions as their multiplication?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I am modelling flow in a tube. I have the functions A(t) and Q(t), corresponding to the area and flow, respectively, where the tube is compliant and can change its cross-sectional area. I can calculate the flow velocity V(t) by V(t) = Q(t)/A(t);

I know that in the frequency domain, if I take the FFT of Q(t) I get F(Q(t)) = Q(w). Similarly F(A(t)) = F(w), and F(V(t)) = V(w).

I also know that Q(w) = conv(A(w),V(w)) where conv is the convolution integral. I was wondering are there any cases where I can approximate the convolution as Q(w)~A(w)*V(w)?

I am trying to come up with an approximate analytical solution in the frequency domain and such assumption would greatly simplify things. Are there any cases where this approximation could be close to be valid?

Comment: Is $t$ time? That is are you considering only $t > 0$? Also how do you define convolution here? What is the domain?

Comment: Yes, t is time and I am considering t>0 only. I guess I am using the general definition of the convolution, which, in the frequency domain, is: Q(w) = $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty A(\tau) V (t- \tau) d \tau $$

Comment: Well if $t > 0$, would the convolution be defined this way? What is $A$ or $V$ when the argument is less than 0? Should it be $\int_0^t$ instead?

Comment: For t<0, A and V are in steady-state (either both periodically fluctuating around a baseline value or both are constant). I am not entirely sure about which definition of convolution to use tbh. I reckon I am most interested in the behaviour at t>0.

Comment: The only cases that come to mind are when either $A(\omega)$ or $V(\omega)$ is a constant, which would mean one of them is a $\delta(t-t_0)$ function in the other domain.